# how can i apply css for xaml?

Tags: css, xaml

Thanks to the thosands of programmers who are making this site such a helpful and awesome site.

I am very new to silverlight(xaml).
I am very much familiar with html and css.
Now my question is how can i apply ***CSS*** to the **button or textbox or link in *XAML***

Answer (score 1):

Styling in XAML works a bit differently than in HTML.
This link shows an example of how to use "stylesheets" type functionality in XAML

http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=howtos&id=5

Comment: Link does not take to the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

You must using resources ...
[Resources overveiw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)